# How can I get value of input array

Tags: javascript

**I want to get value of input **

```
 <input class="text-left" readonly id = "editable_text" name = "editable_text[<?php echo $order['id']; ?>]" style="vertical-align: middle" value="<?PHP echo $order['issued_to']; ?>">
 <input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="orders[]" id ="orders"  value="<?php echo $order['id']; ?>" onclick="uncheckMain_arayish()">

    var x = document.getElementsByName("orders[]");
    var text = document.getElementsByName("editable_text[]");
     for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    if (x[i].checked) {
                        var order = x[i].value;
                        text[order].readOnly = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        text[i].readOnly = true;
                    }
                }
```

> **"text" is not working properly.**

Comment: I am not getting what is the issue here. What is your main question?

Comment: I want to get input data like "x = document.getElementsByName("editable_text[]"); " which array ID can be different for example  alert (x[67].value) but it is not working and I do not understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("editable_text").value
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: var text = document.getElementsByName("editable_text[]"); I use ByName not ID

Comment: Yes but since every ID within your DOM should be unique you could just get this text-input by his id.

Comment: I have lots of input I only can decide it because of array id which is in my code this (name = "editable_text[<?php echo $order['id']; ?>]")

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array from `var text = document.getElementsByName("editable_text[]");` and then you try to access an object based on `order.id`

This will only work in a very specific case.

You should generate unique id's for text based on order ids

```
<input class="text-left" readonly id = "editable_text[<?php echo $order['id']; ?>]" name = "editable_text[<?php echo $order['id']; ?>]" style="vertical-align: middle" value="<?PHP echo $order['issued_to']; ?>">
```

And then you can use `document.getElementById` inside your for to get the associated text element.

Comment: I checked it before it does not work in ID we cannot use " [ ] " this

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are trying to get all `text` elements like:

```
var text = document.getElementsByName("editable_text[]");
```

But the `name` of the attribute is not exactly like `editable_text[]` but more like `editable_text[12]` or `editable_text[67]` and so on. So, you can get all these `text` elements like:

```
var text = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='editable_text']");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var text = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='editable_text']");
text.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el.name, el.value) // use this for debugging purpose
})
```

```html
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[10]" value="1">
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[12]" value="2">
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[14]" value="3">
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[16]" value="4">
```

---

Also, using `text[order].readOnly = false;` will not work, as `text` is a DOM element we cannot simply call it like that. You can instead use:

```
document.querySelector("[name='editable_text[" + order + "]']").readOnly = false;
```

**Demo:**

```js
var text = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='editable_text']");
var order = 12;

text.forEach(function(el) {
  // Disable only the name="editable_text[12]" input like
  document.querySelector("[name='editable_text[" + order + "]']").disabled = true;
})
```

```html
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[10]" value="1">
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[12]" value="2">
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[14]" value="3">
<input class="text-left" readonly name="editable_text[16]" value="4">
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, now I want to write  "document.getElementsByName("editable_text[67]").readonly  = false;" , but it is not working.  what is problem here whet do you think?

Comment: I have already mentioned about it and added a solution also in the 2nd demo.

Comment: btw, `document.getElementsByName("editable_text[67]")[0].readonly = false;` should work fine, this happens because `getElementsByName` returns an array of dom nodes, not a single node.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) to help future users too. Thanks!